# Lost the drive size bars in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, disk-space

I've recently lost the size bar under the hard dives in Windows Explorer at work, on a Windows 7 Pro laptop.

[It used to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsXbn.jpg) but now [it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onmiZ.png).

How can I get the size bar back?

Addendum: Both of these pictures are of the same "View" setting, which is "Extended Tiles". I'm not using different views on each photo, that would be silly of me. Instead, the Tiles view that should show the size bars, and did so in the past, is not not showing me the size bar.

Regards,

seePyou

Comment: [Disk Space Usage Bar Missing in This PC](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/disk-space-usage-bar-missing-this-pc-my-computer/)

Comment: Try resetting the folder view. `Options -> View -> Reset Folders`

Comment: Suggested by fred_dot_u, did not help though.

Comment: Check [this answer on the MS forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/disk-space-usage-bar-in-my-computer-is-missing/457ab86b-54c4-4f11-ac52-49739978ad31).

Comment: Deleted the registry folder bags, nothing changed. I find it interesting that another user in that thread mentioned that he, like me, doesn't have a TILES view, but an EXTENDED TILES view. Maybe some update forced this change and I need to get my TILES view back?

Comment: Also followed other guides of deleting Bag and BagMRU from multiple places in the registry, the view is still Extended Tiles and the size bar is still missing.

Answer (score 0):

Right click in an empty area of the window, select View, Tiles

Comment: That is the view I am using, the view that is presented by my screenshot, no size bars. Might be important to note that there is no Tiles, but only Extended Tiles?

Comment: @Ramhound - thank you for your suggestion, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

See if resetting the folder views helps.

From **[Disk Space Usage Bar Missing in This PC](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/disk-space-usage-bar-missing-this-pc-my-computer/)**

Open File Explorer and click This PC. From the File menu, click Change folder and search options. Click the View tab and click Reset Folders. This resets the This PC view to defaults.

Comment: Reset Folders pressed, was asked if I'm sure, said yes, nothing changed. Still no bars.

Comment: I also checked the registry as the linked article suggested, but the registry already had the same string, character for character.